# Where can I set validateAuthority to false when setting B2C redirect urls to b2clogin.com

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

According to the [Set redirect URLs to b2clogin.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/b2clogin) documentation, we need to mark `validateAuthority` as `false`.

Do you know where should put this following code? Is that at `startup.cs`?

```
this.clientApplication = new UserAgentApplication( env.auth.clientId, env.auth.loginAuthority, this.authCallback.bind(this), { validateAuthority: false } );
```

Comment: Are you developing a JavaScript or .NET app?

Answer (score 0):

The key point to that documentation is that when you instantiate MSAL, you should set ValidateAuthority to false in whichever form the specific MSAL library you are using supports it.

The code snippet in the documentation is specifically for [MSAL.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js), which the snippet is probably using for a single page application (SPA) where this code would go in [the top-level init code in index.html](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-msal-singlepageapp/blob/7b68322a9a020cf23197534e677537a7915c7143/index.html#L48).

For C# web applications (assuming that's what you're interested in based on your mention of `startup.cs`:

- Use [MSAL for .Net](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet)
- Set the MSAL client's ValidateAuthority property to false every time you instantiate it which generally occurs:

  - In the [OnAuthorizationCodeReceived event handler](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi/blob/88a218d2ccaafdd490af80d3d4f7a543f1a4a736/TaskWebApp/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs#L146), and
  - In the [Controller method calling the B2C API](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi/blob/88a218d2ccaafdd490af80d3d4f7a543f1a4a736/TaskWebApp/Controllers/TasksController.cs#L31)

Comment: it's fixed by your suggestion! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to login with your B2C account into this app with `b2clogin.com` endpoints , you get following error message: Authority validation is not supported for this type of authority. It shows as below screenshot:

[image]

## Resolution:

As Saca said, it should set the the MSAL client's `ValidateAuthority` property to be `false`.

For [this ASP.NET Web App](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi), we can just change the `ValidateAuthority` property by adding it  in [`OnAuthorizationCodeReceived event handler`](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi/blob/88a218d2ccaafdd490af80d3d4f7a543f1a4a736/TaskWebApp/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs#L146) from `Startup.Auth.cs` file:

```
 ConfidentialClientApplication cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(ClientId, Authority, RedirectUri, new ClientCredential(ClientSecret), userTokenCache, null) { ValidateAuthority = false} ;
```

In the `TasksController.cs` file, you can also set it here:

```
 ConfidentialClientApplication cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(Startup.ClientId, Startup.Authority, Startup.RedirectUri, new ClientCredential(Startup.ClientSecret), userTokenCache, null) { ValidateAuthority = false} ;
```